# Is styling css with nested <div> always commutative?

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-experience, visual-web-developer

I am trying to understand whether the order in which you define css styling using div tags matters.

Is:

```html
<div class="some styling 1">
  <div class="some styling 2">
  Some content
  </div>
</div>
```

Always the same as:

```html
<div class="some styling 2">
  <div class="some styling 1">
  Some content
  </div>
</div>
```

?

Thanks!

Comment: not it's not ....

Comment: ^ trivial example : margin > border != border > margin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly not, if you were for instance to put

```
border: 2px solid #000000;
padding: 5px;
```

on `some styling 1`, and
`padding: 5px;` on `some styling 2`

The first instance will produce a box with a border on the outside box and the content will have a `padding` of `5px` relative to the `border`, plus `5px` of `padding` relative to the inner box, meaning the content will have `10px padding` and an outer border.
Here the `border` is `10px` away from the content

The second instance will produce a box with an outer `padding` of `5px` then a `2px border` followed by `5px padding` then the content. As you can see the `border` has now shifted position and is `5px` away from the content